# Find a square, stochastic matrix of odd size, not a permutation matrix, with an eigenvalue other than 1 on the unit circle

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues, matrix-theory, stochastic-matrices

...or prove that none exists.

Note that such a matrix $M$ couldn't be primitive, so there would be at least one entry equal to zero in every power $M^k$ (Perron-Frobenius theory).

Preferably the matrix would have a diagonal that is not all zero, and at the risk of making the problem imprecise, I'd like to find such a matrix with as few zeros and ones as possible.

Thank you.

Comment: The matrix [[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,0]] meets your description (it has an eigenvalue of -1), but I'm guessing that's not what you intended.  Maybe you want to require the eigenvalue to be non-real?

Comment: @Bill, that's not stochastic (but if you change the last row to $[0,0,1]$, it is).

Comment: @GerryMyerson, but if you make said change it becomes a permutation matrix.

Answer (score 6):

$$\pmatrix{0&1&.5\cr1&0&.5\cr0&0&0\cr}$$ has $-1$ as an eigenvalue.

Comment: All the column sums are 1, all the entries are non-negative. What definition are you using? (If you want the rows to sum to 1, just take the transpose).

Answer (score 3):

If you want a doubly stochastic matrix,
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
0&1 & 0&0&0 \\
1&0 & 0&0&0 \\
0&0 & 1/3&1/3&1/3 \\
0&0 & 1/3&1/3&1/3 \\
0&0 & 1/3&1/3&1/3 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
has eigenvalue $-1$.

Answer (score 3):

All examples in the answers given so far are block triangular with a permutation matrix as the diagonal block with the critical eigenvalue.

If you want something different, you can take
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
A & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & A\\
0 & A & 0
\end{bmatrix}, \quad A = \begin{bmatrix}1/2 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & 1/2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
This matrix has a diagonal that is not all zero, and contains no entries equal to 1.

Answer (score 2):

The [Karpelevič theorem](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379517300253) will make it difficult for the matrix not to at least involve a permutation matrix (notice that the upper-left $2$-by-$2$ block of the matrix given by Gerry is a permutation matrix).

If $C_n$ is the $n$-by-$n$ defined by $C_n = [e_n \mid e_1 \mid \cdots \mid e_{n-1}]$, i.e., $C_n$ is the adjancency matrix of a directed $n$-cycle, where $e_i$ denotes the $i^\text{th}$ canonical basis vector of $\mathbb{C}^n$, then the $n$-by-$n$ (row) stochastic matrix 
$$ M_n :=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & e_1^\top \\
0 & C_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}$$
has spectrum $\sigma(M) = \{ 0, 1, \omega,\dots,\omega^{n-1}\}$, where $\omega:=\exp(2\pi i/n)$. Thus, $M_n$ has $n-2$ eigenvalues (distinct from unity) on the unit-circle.

For instance, the matrix 
$$ M_5=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
\end{bmatrix} $$
has spectrum $\{0,\pm 1, \pm i\}$.